# "The binary you uploaded was invalid" with ErrorNoPermissionsToReadFile , error code 1102

Tags: xcode, app-store-connect

[image]

While archiving my app to upload it to iTunes Connect, I received "The binary you uploaded was invalid". The log shows error = 1102, which is ErrorNoPermissionsToReadFile. I don't get any specifics as to where it might be. I added an In App Purchase to this new app version, and I can't figure out if that's related.

My app has two targets, a Pro and a Lite version. The main target is the Pro version. I added the IAP to the Lite version and also changed its CKContainer (iCloud) to use the same one as the Pro version. It all works correctly when I test it on devices, and the Pro version uploaded to iTunes Connect with no problems.

I'm using Xcode 10.1. I also tried uploading it with the latest version of Application Loader, and it also didn't work. It gave me the same error.

*`This is some of the logged info:`*

```
[2019-03-14 10:42:22 CET] <main> DBG-X:   parameter StreamingSettings = {LogStreamingEnabled=true, MultipartUploadsEnabled=true, AssetDescriptionStreamingEnabled=false}

[2019-03-14 10:42:24 CET] <main>  INFO: The session's final state is Failed

[2019-03-14 10:42:24 CET] <main>  INFO: JSON:{"msg":{"phase":"Upload","count":3,"description":"Validating assets","index":3},"messageType":"VerifyProgress"}

[2019-03-14 10:42:24 CET] <main> DEBUG: Using token file path /Users/myMac/Library/Caches/com.apple.amp.itmstransporter/UploadTokens/myMac.local_AJXXXXRX58_12700000953.itmsp.token

[2019-03-14 10:42:24 CET] <main> DEBUG: Attempting exclusive file lock on token file

[2019-03-14 10:42:24 CET] <main> DEBUG: Token exists, examining

[2019-03-14 10:42:24 CET] <main> DEBUG: Token pid: 66666, found process = false; my pid: 68317

[2019-03-14 10:42:24 CET] <main> DBG-X: Memory: [JVM] 1024M free, 1129M total, 1820M max [System] (Physical) 12776M free, 32768M total (Swap) 0 free, 0 total

[2019-03-14 10:42:24 CET] <main>  INFO: JSON:{"msg":{"phase":"Upload","count":3,"description":"Validating assets","index":4},"messageType":"VerifyProgress"}

[2019-03-14 10:42:24 CET] <main> DBG-X: Deflated 622 bytes to 456

[2019-03-14 10:42:24 CET] <main> DBG-X: Using operation named: validateAssets

[2019-03-14 10:42:24 CET] <main> DBG-X: Apple's web service operation input parameters:

[2019-03-14 10:42:24 CET] <main> DBG-X:   parameter Application = iTMSTransporter

[2019-03-14 10:42:24 CET] <main> DBG-X:   parameter BaseVersion = 1.11.0

[2019-03-14 10:42:24 CET] <main> DBG-X:   parameter Client = Application Loader

[2019-03-14 10:42:24 CET] <main> DBG-X:   parameter ClientVersion = 3.7.2 (1138)

[2019-03-14 10:42:24 CET] <main> DBG-X:   parameter Files = [metadata.xml, MyApp.ipa]

[2019-03-14 10:42:24 CET] <main> DBG-X:   parameter ItcProviderName = AGXX28RX59

[2019-03-14 10:42:24 CET] <main> DBG-X:   parameter MetadataCompressed = (suppressed)

[2019-03-14 10:42:24 CET] <main> DBG-X:   parameter MetadataInfo = {app_platform=ios, primary_bundle_identifier=, device_id=, bundle_identifier=com.myCompany.myApp-LiteVersion, packageVersion=software5.4, apple_id=xxxxxxxxx, asset_types=[bundle], bundle_version=4.0, bundle_short_version_string=4.0}

[2019-03-14 10:42:24 CET] <main> DBG-X:   parameter OSIdentifier = Mac OS X 10.13.6 (x86_64); jvm=25.71-b02; jre=1.8.0-u131-b11-iTMSTransporter-b02

[2019-03-14 10:42:24 CET] <main> DBG-X:   parameter PackageName = 1200000953.itmsp

[2019-03-14 10:42:24 CET] <main> DBG-X:   parameter PackageSize = 340456550

[2019-03-14 10:42:24 CET] <main> DBG-X:   parameter Transport = Aspera

[2019-03-14 10:42:24 CET] <main> DBG-X:   parameter TransporterArguments = -m upload -u myApp@mail.com -vp json -dsToken **hidden value** -itc_provider AJXXXXRX58 -f /var/folders/c8/z33nwjvefuihgkuifvjhr0000gn/T/04A2DB68-001E-4D49-B66C-BJ4J7K3K69B4A6/120000953.itmsp -indicator true -v eXtreme -Dtransporter.client=Application Loader -Dtransporter.client.version=3.7.2 (1138)

[2019-03-14 10:42:24 CET] <main> DBG-X:   parameter Version = 1.13.0

[2019-03-14 10:42:24 CET] <main> DBG-X:   parameter iTMSTransporterMode = upload

[2019-03-14 10:42:24 CET] <main>  INFO: iTMSTransporter Correlation Key: 5778ffb9-3dbb-327b-87fb-c8b34hw8fb2c

[2019-03-14 10:42:31 CET] <main> DBG-X: Apple's web service operation return value:

[2019-03-14 10:42:31 CET] <main> DBG-X:   parameter EnableJWTForAllCalls = false

[2019-03-14 10:42:31 CET] <main> DBG-X:   parameter MinimumFileSizeThresholdForCheckum = 104857600

[2019-03-14 10:42:31 CET] <main> DBG-X:   parameter SoftwareMediaDescriptionFormat = binary

[2019-03-14 10:42:31 CET] <main> DBG-X:   parameter RestartClient = false

[2019-03-14 10:42:31 CET] <main> DBG-X:   parameter SoftwareMediaDescriptionThresholds = {in-app-purchase-content={extensions=[pkg], size=100000000}, ccats={extensions=[pdf], size=100000000}, product-archive={extensions=[pkg], size=100000000}, developer-id-package={extensions=[zip, pkg, dmg], size=100000000}, bundle={extensions=[zip, ipa], size=100000000}, large-icon={extensions=[jpg, png, jpeg], size=100000000}}

[2019-03-14 10:42:31 CET] <main> DBG-X:   parameter Success = false

[2019-03-14 10:42:31 CET] <main> DBG-X:   parameter Errors = [ERROR ITMS-90706: "The binary you uploaded was invalid.", ERROR ITMS-90707: "The binary you uploaded was invalid."]

[2019-03-14 10:42:31 CET] <main> DBG-X:   parameter FilesToUpload = [metadata.xml, MyApp.ipa]

[2019-03-14 10:42:31 CET] <main> DBG-X:   parameter AssetsToDescribe = [{Role=source, Filename=MyApp.ipa, ShouldDescribeAsset=true, UTI=com.apple.ipa}]

[2019-03-14 10:42:31 CET] <main> DBG-X:   parameter Checksums = {MyApp.ipa=24959b4e7b8bcre78bf738bf3a4bdea1f}

[2019-03-14 10:42:31 CET] <main> DBG-X:   parameter FileSizes = {MyApp.ipa=340455928}

[2019-03-14 10:42:31 CET] <main> DBG-X:   parameter ErrorCode = 1102

[2019-03-14 10:42:31 CET] <main> DBG-X:   parameter ErrorMessage = ERROR ITMS-90706: "The binary you uploaded was invalid."
ERROR ITMS-90707: "The binary you uploaded was invalid.
 (1102)

[2019-03-14 10:42:31 CET] <main> ERROR: ERROR ITMS-90706: "The binary you uploaded was invalid."

[2019-03-14 10:42:31 CET] <main> ERROR: ERROR ITMS-90707: "The binary you uploaded was invalid."

[2019-03-14 10:42:31 CET] <main> DBG-X: The error code is: 1102

[2019-03-14 10:42:31 CET] <main>  INFO: Done performing authentication.

[2019-03-14 10:42:31 CET] <main>  INFO: JSON:{"msg":{"phase":"Upload","count":3,"description":"Operation failed","index":3},"messageType":"VerifyProgress"}

[2019-03-14 10:42:31 CET] <main> DBG-X: Returning 1

Package Summary:

1 package(s) were not uploaded because they had problems:
    /var/folders/c8/z33nw7chiusda6r5yf4uurg4ytg4y8r0000gn/T/04A2DB68-001E-4D49-B66C-BF15F3GY4A6/120000953.itmsp - Error Messages:
        ERROR ITMS-90706: "The binary you uploaded was invalid."
        ERROR ITMS-90707: "The binary you uploaded was invalid."
```

I've spent a week trying a lot of answers from this site, and Apple Dev forums, but none has worked so far. I'm losing it! Your help will be much appreciated.

**UPDATE:**

I found out what I did wrong. In case it helps someone, in my info.plist I had the icon-files(iOS 5) and icons ~iPad keys set. I deleted those keys and it archived and uploaded to iTunes Connect without any problems. Yay!! =D

Comment: Did you try to upload the build after changing the iCloud (CKContainer) to some unique id?

Comment: No, I changed the CKContainer and after testing it works correctly, I added the IAP. That was about 2 weeks ago, all worked well.